# Node. Js Upload assets like video images files

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm building an website using react and Node, the requirements is to upload video, images or any files
My question is should i save the file to the database or just upload to any cloud provider I mean which is the common way use in Node
And is it correct to store it in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases aren't typically suited to file storage, especially as the file size increases.

Instead, you could look at a products and services that are tailored towards file storage like [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage).

You could then store a reference or path to your files in your database should you need to keep track of, and query them in the context of your system.

Comment: Agreed. But you can start by placing the files in a directory in the file system of your server.  [Read this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload). When that works correctly, you can work on putting them into cloud storage.